# Script paypal with jquery and hashtags

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script paypal but is not working with jquery and hashtags

is working if call the page like  http://name.com/shop.php
but is not working call the page like http://name.com/#shop

this is my script:

```
<div id="sett-title"> Simple. Easy. Affordable. </div>
We have made the process of buying social media services ultra simple and user friendly. Just simply follow these steps.
</br>
<a class="glyphicons circle_arrow_right"><i></i></a>Choose a service from below</br>
<a class="glyphicons circle_arrow_right"><i></i></a>Select your package</br>
<a class="glyphicons circle_arrow_right"><i></i></a>Enter your details (URL, username etc.)</br>
<a class="glyphicons circle_arrow_right"><i></i></a>Pay for your order</br>
<a class="glyphicons circle_arrow_right"><i></i></a>We deliver your order within 72 hours.</br>

</br>
<div class="infobox"><center>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#content').load('fb.php'); window.location.hash = 'Shop';" class="button" style="width:120px;text-align:center">Facebook</a></center></div>
<hr style="margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px">
<div align="center">

<table width="100%"><tr><td>
<?php
  $queryRes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `shop` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
for($j=1; $shop = mysql_fetch_object($queryRes); $j++) {

?>
<div class="buy_boxs">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr style="height:40px">


                        <div id="title-premium-boxs"><span style="margin: 30px"><span class="glyphicons face"><i></i><?=$shop->name?> </span></span></div>

                    <div class="gray-area">24-72 hour delivery</div>
                    <ul class="special" style="margin: 10px 22px 10px 40px">



<li>
<strong><?=$shop->nr1?></strong>
<?=$shop->media?>
<span class="away">$<?=$shop->price1?></span>
</li>
<li>
<strong><?=$shop->nr2?></strong>
<?=$shop->media?>
<span class="away">$<?=$shop->price2?></span>
</li>
<li>
<strong><?=$shop->nr3?></strong>
<?=$shop->media?>
<span class="away">$<?=$shop->price3?></span>
</li>
<li>
<strong><?=$shop->nr4?></strong>
<?=$shop->media?>
<span class="away">$<?=$shop->price4?></span>
</li>
<li>
<strong><?=$shop->nr5?></strong>
<?=$shop->media?>
<span class="away">$<?=$shop->price5?></span>
</li>
</ul></a>


               <script language="javascript">
                   function setPrice<?=$j?>()
                   {

                       value              = $("#item_number<?=$j?> :selected").val();
                       option_text<?=$j?> = $("#item_number<?=$j?> :selected").text();
                       arr_data<?=$j?>    = option_text<?=$j?>.split("—");
                       price<?=$j?>       = arr_data<?=$j?>[1].replace('$','');
                       custom<?=$j?>      = $("#custom<?=$j?>").val();

                      $("#item_name<?=$j?>").val(option_text<?=$j?>+' '+custom<?=$j?>);
                      $("#item_number<?=$j?>").val(value);
                      $("#amount<?=$j?>").val(price<?=$j?>);

                   }
                </script>       

                <select class="selection" name="item_number<?=$j?>" id="item_number<?=$j?>" style="margin: 10px 22px 10px 25px; width: 201px" onchange="setPrice<?=$j?>();">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option data-price="15" value="TF1000"> <?=$shop->nr1?> <?=$shop->media?> — $0.02 </option>
                        <option data-price="20" value="TF5000"> <?=$shop->nr3?> <?=$shop->media?> — $<?=$shop->price2?> </option>
                        <option data-price="30" value="TF10000"> <?=$shop->nr3?> <?=$shop->media?> — $<?=$shop->price3?> </option>
                        <option data-price="75" value="TF50000"> <?=$shop->nr4?> <?=$shop->media?> — $<?=$shop->price4?> </option>
                        <option data-price="150" value="TF100000"> <?=$shop->nr5?> <?=$shop->media?> — $<?=$shop->price5?> </option>
                </select>
                    <div class="gray-area extrapadding">
<input style="margin: -14px 23px 10px 25px; width: 188px;" type="text" placeholder="<?=$shop->placeholder?>" name="custom<?=$j?>" id="custom<?=$j?>">
</div>


                <script language="javascript">
                 function checkerror<?=$j?>()
                 {

                    value              = $("#item_number<?=$j?> :selected").val();
                    option_text<?=$j?> = $("#item_number<?=$j?> :selected").text();
                    custom<?=$j?>      = $("#custom<?=$j?>").val();
                    $("#item_name<?=$j?>").val(option_text<?=$j?>+' '+custom<?=$j?>);


                    custom<?=$j?>      = $("#custom<?=$j?>").val();

                    if(custom<?=$j?>=="")
                    {
                      alert("Fanpage URL / Facebook Username is a required filed");
                      return false;
                    }

                 }
                </script>

                    <div style="text-align:right">
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onsubmit="return checkerror<?=$j?>();">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" id="business" value="mail@yahoo.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name<?=$j?>"  value="<? echo $site->site_brand;?> <? echo $pack->name;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" id="item_number<?=$j?>" value="<? echo $pack->coins;?>+ Credits">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<? echo $data->id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount<?=$j?>" value="<? echo $pack->price;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?echo $site->site_url;?>/return.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?echo $site->site_url;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?echo $site->site_url;?>/ipn.php">
<!--<input style="width:80px;border:none;background:none;" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" /><img alt="" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />-->
<input style="width: 151px;border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; margin: 10px 22px 10px 25px; width: 201px" type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now" class="button" />

</form>


                            </div>

                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>

</div>      
<?php } ?>

</td></tr></table>

<br clear="all">
<br>
<b><?=$lang['sp85']?></b><br>
<br>
<span style="font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;"><?=$lang['sp86']?></span>
<?
```

Please need a help.. thank you!!